# How to programmatically execute the Network Setup Wizard and cofigure a lan connection with static ips using C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I am creating an application that is connecting to another computer through an Ethernet cable in XP. I need to execute the network setup wizard to setup a local area connection (with File sharing Turned On) and then set static ips and the default gateway; all this programmatically using C#. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with INetCfg as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547694%28VS.85%29.aspx). It's a Win32 API so you'd have to use PInvoke, as discussed [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/), and you should be able to find samples for calling it from C# by a search for `INetCfg` and `C#` or similar.

Comment: It's not as easy as it sound. If it's done using C++ it's going to be easy. There is no COM interface defined for INetCfg. Have to resort to C++ for this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20167/Exploring-Network-Configuration-with-the-INetCfg-C